# Uncaught at check error starting React-Native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an almost fresh ignite react-native app and I get this error immediately every time I reload the app. I'm new to react-native and not really sure how to fix this or even where it's originating from. If I dismiss the error, my app seems to work as expected but the error just comes back next reload.

Here's the entire error:

```
console.error: "uncaught at check", "call: argument fn is undefined"
error
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\YellowBox.js:67:16
log
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\redux-saga\lib\internal\utils.js:235:19
check
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\redux-saga\lib\internal\utils.js:51:8
getFnCallDesc
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\redux-saga\lib\internal\io.js:113:20
call
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\redux-saga\lib\internal\io.js:138:36
getUserAvatar$
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\App\Sagas\GithubSagas.js:8:30
tryCatch
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:63:44
invoke
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:337:30
<unknown>
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\regenerator-runtime\runtime.js:96:28
next
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\redux-saga\lib\internal\proc.js:311:31
proc
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\redux-saga\lib\internal\proc.js:270:2
runForkEffect
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\redux-saga\lib\internal\proc.js:547:23
runEffect
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\redux-saga\lib\internal\proc.js:434:590
next
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\redux-saga\lib\internal\proc.js:315:18
currCb
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\redux-saga\lib\internal\proc.js:388:9
takeCb
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\redux-saga\lib\internal\proc.js:459:110
put
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\redux-saga\lib\internal\channel.js:87:18
<unknown>
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\redux-saga\lib\internal\channel.js:163:13
<unknown>
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\redux-saga\lib\internal\channel.js:186:11
emit
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\redux-saga\lib\internal\channel.js:40:13
<unknown>
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\redux-saga\lib\internal\middleware.js:87:25
<unknown>
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\App\Redux\ScreenTrackingMiddleware.js:21:16
dispatch
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\redux\lib\applyMiddleware.js:45:27
sagaDispatch
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\redux-saga\lib\internal\utils.js:257:20
<unknown>
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\redux-saga\lib\internal\proc.js:482:52
exec
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\redux-saga\lib\internal\scheduler.js:28:4
flush
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\redux-saga\lib\internal\scheduler.js:69:9
asap
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\redux-saga\lib\internal\scheduler.js:42:4
<unknown>
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\redux-saga\lib\internal\channel.js:189:27
emit
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\redux-saga\lib\internal\channel.js:40:13
<unknown>
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\redux-saga\lib\internal\middleware.js:87:25
<unknown>
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\App\Redux\ScreenTrackingMiddleware.js:21:16
startup
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\App\Containers\RootContainer.js:31:26
componentDidMount
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\App\Containers\RootContainer.js:15:6
proxiedComponentDidMount
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\react-proxy\modules\createPrototypeProxy.js:61:45
<unknown>
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactCompositeComponent.js:377:18
measureLifeCyclePerf
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactCompositeComponent.js:63:11
<unknown>
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactCompositeComponent.js:377:12
notifyAll
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\CallbackQueue.js:75:26
close
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\native\ReactNativeReconcileTransaction.js:36:4
closeAll
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\Transaction.js:223:29
perform
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\Transaction.js:165:24
batchedMountComponentIntoNode
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\native\ReactNativeMount.js:73:4
perform
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\Transaction.js:152:24
batchedUpdates
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:61:33
batchedUpdates
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\shared\stack\reconciler\ReactUpdates.js:92:41
renderComponent
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\native\ReactNativeMount.js:149:6
render
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\src\renderers\native\ReactNativeStack.js:30:42
renderApplication
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\renderApplication.js:34:4
run
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\AppRegistry.js:119:10
runApplication
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\AppRegistry.js:196:26
__callFunction
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:245:47
<unknown>
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:101:26
__guard
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:213:6
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
    C:\Users\jlok\Documents\reactignite\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:100:17
```